# Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'. MVC, ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, ado.net, web-config, connection-string

I have a MVC WebAPI project and a ADO.NET Entity Framework project in one solution. I am connecting and working with the database from the ADO.NET Entity Framework project, but when I add the ado.net project to the MVC WebAPI project so that I can store data in the database the same connection string is not working that works in the ADO.NET project.

I've copied the connection string from the ado.net project and pasted it into the web.config file of the mvc project and I am getting the initial catalog keyword not supported.

Below is the connection string that connects perfectly from the ADO.NET project but does not work in the MVC project.

```
 <add name="StorefrontSystemEntities1"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.csdl|res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.ssdl|res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=data source=localhost;initial catalog=StorefrontSystem;persist security info=True;user id=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what happened here but it is working now.. I noticed that for provider connection string the " " are " &quot.

```
<add name="StorefrontSystemEntities1"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.csdl|res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.ssdl|res://*/StorefrontSystemDB.msl;
   provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
   provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=StorefrontSystem;persist security info=True;
   user id=XXX;password=XXXXX
   MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have no idea what happened here.